# how to interpret this timestamp?

Tags: c, unix, timestamp, utc

Lets say this is the time-stamp: `2011-07-06T00:00:35.851-07:00`

What does that tell me? This is how I am trying to understand it:

```
2011-07-06 - date
00:00:35   - hh:mm:ss
851        - micro seconds??
07:00      - what does that tell me?
```

I need to convert this to UTC if possible with C.

Edit 0: Thanks for the responses by @RichieHindle and @Marc B. I now understand the GMT offset. 
My problem now is, I am not getting correct value out of getdate.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

Comment: Do you live in Pacific Daylight Time?  That's what -07:00 corresponds with.

Comment: yes, I do live in PDT, what meaning does that convey?

Comment: It's `-07:00`, which means you are 7 hours behind UTC.  Please read the link I posted in the first comment above.

Comment: @Alok: Thanks, I guess, I am good now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`851` is milliseconds (thousandths of a second) and `-07:00` is the timezone (UTC minus 7 hours).

Comment: Thanks Richie and @Marc B:  I am trying to parse this and convert this into UTC this way: 1) get 2011-07-06T07:00:35 ( I am not concerned about 851) 2) apply gettime() on it 3) add 07:00 to the result of 2). --- Is this the correct way to go about it?

Comment: Richie and @Marc B: Somehow, converting `2011-07-06T00:00:35` using getdate is giving me `Tue Jul  5 10:00:35 2011` -- I do not understand why.

Comment: Same way for `2011-07-15T17:50:24` => `Fri Jul 15 03:50:24 2011` and for `2011-07-15T18:00:00` => `Fri Jul 15 04:00:00 2011` ---I am not able to understand this behavior.

Comment: @hari: It looks like the `-7:00` is being counted twice - is that possible?  You might like to use `strptime` rather than `getdate` because it lets you specify the format of your dates.  You get more control that way.  If none of this helps, I suggest opening a new question and including your source code.

Answer (score 5):

It says it's July 6th, 2011, 35.851 seconds past midnight, in the GMT-7 time zone. To convert to UTC (GMT-0 timezone), you'd need to add 7 hours (-7 + 7 = 0), making it `2011-07-06T07:00:35.851-00:00`